# Hibernate Entity is unexpectedly updated

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a springboot/hibernate application where one of the database tables is updated frequently unexpectedly, the records are being accessed and set to the same values with just increasing the version field referring to the number of modifications.

In the application, this table's records are only updated in one place as intended, and it is referenced in some other entities which are only reading it, and it is referenced as follow

```
@Id
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID", updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private MyEntity entity;
```

I doubt that some flows in this app are indirectly updating it, but this seems to be false from tracing the code. What can I try to figure out where are these `update` statements coming from? could it be a hibernate issue or an issue in designing the JPA Entities?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend logging your sql/hql calls so you can try to trace where it's being updated. In hibernate you can turn that on with this configuration:

If you are using hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
```

If you are using JPA:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
```